# Solution for voting without attachment to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My application is one page contract. I would like users to be able to sign the contract by clicking on a button. The contract is *not* a resource; it's plain HTML.

Every solution I have found so far relies on having a model that `acts as votable`. How can I implement a simple button that users may only click once, and display the number of users who have clicked it?

Comment: you probably wouldn't use ruby/rails for that at all.

Comment: What should I use, then? I'm all for learning something new.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with static pages, at least not in a way that is clean and secure.

Think about it this way: every user is looking at a *copy* of the contract, which is being displayed to them on their browser (the client). If you want users to be able to cast votes that persist and be aware of votes cast by other users, then you need a server that keeps track of it centrally. That's why the solutions you have found so far rely on having a model, presumably backed with a table.